# How many giant kelp are there per square meter?

Tags: ecology, population-biology, algae

In a high-density giant kelp (Macrocystis pyrifera) bed how many "holdfasts" or roots would there be per square meter of seafloor on average?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For example, please add in the species of "giant kelp" for which you want a density. Have you done any research to try to answer this yourself? Please summarize what you found (and where) and what  you still wish to know. Thanks! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density of *Macrocystis pyrifera* is pretty variable. According to [Dayton et al. 1984](https://doi.org/10.2307/1942498) off of the Southern California coast it can range from **less than 0.1 to to 1.0 $individuals/m^2$**. The variation depends on the location, where there are different exposure levels to high energy waves, upwellings containing nutrients, and predation by sea urchin.

Dayton, P. K., Currie, V., Gerrodette, T., Keller, B. D., Rosenthal, R., & Tresca, D. V. (1984). Patch dynamics and stability of some California kelp communities. Ecological monographs, 54(3), 253-289. https://doi.org/10.2307/1942498